# MSXML / XPath: special Characters

Tags: xpath, msxml

I'm reading and writing XML-files with Microsoft XML Core Services 6.0 (MSXML). 
When writing element-content with "special" chars that have to be escaped
in the context of xml, like writing "`&`" as `&amp;` i dont have to care 
about this because MSXML does this conversion. This means, if i assign a text
to an element, e.g. `oXMLElement.Text = "1 & 2"` , MSXML actually writes 
`oXMLElement.Text = 1 &amp; 2` when i create a XML-file. Thats pretty nice
and saves me some work.

Now, what i want to do, is to "de-mask" XML-strings
automatically. So, i read from a XML-file with the `selectNodes`-method, which
works by adding an XPath-statement, e.g. `//ns:element/text()`. Unfortunately,
the result-string i get looks like `1 &amp; 2` and not like `1 & 2`. Is there
a way to tell the MSXML-object or maybe the XPath-statement to give me an
"de-masked" string? I´m using MSXML with ObjectPal / Paradox, so the best 
solution would be a method from the MSXML-library or a "special" XPath-
statement.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using (the `selectNodes()` call and a bit of context)? Especially, how are you getting the result string after calling `selectNodes()`? E.g. are you using one of the properties `.nodeValue`, `.text`, or `.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the "escaped" XML notation for the text. This is what you should see if you use the [`.xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms755989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to retrieve the string.

To get the string without the escapes, use [`.nodeValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).